# Error get timestamp now() by code backend

Tags: postgresql

My config pgsql timezone: UTC

My create function:

```
create function ufn_test_date() returns json
    language plpgsql
as
$$
declare    
    data_return json;    
begin    
    drop table if exists temp_date;
    create temp table temp_date as
    select now();
    ----------------------------------
    select json_agg(t)
    from (select sdc.*from temp_date sdc) t
    into data_return;
    return data_return;
    -----------------------------------
end
$$;
```

========NOW RUN IN pg-client========

select ufn_test_date();

return: [{"now":"2021-09-21T10:49:53.272196+00:00"}]

========run code backend call function========

return: [{"now":"2021-09-21T06:51:49.317205-04:00"}]

Lib connect db: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL version: 5.0.2

Client connect: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore:5.0.3

2 time values are 4 hours apart, pls help me :(

Ex: I only use 1 Postgresql server

=====================================================

Update Fix:

Use:

```
    var dd_builder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString)
            {
                Timezone = "UTC"
            };
    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(dd_builder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

That means the the setting of the `timezone` parameter was different in these two database sessions. When a `timestamp with time zone` is formatted as string, that happens according to the current setting of `timezone`.

Note that the two timestamps are just a few minutes apart, they are just rendered in different time zones.

Comment: you don't understand my question. The results returned when "select function" from postgresql-cli and c# source code are different, when using the same db server

Comment: You don't understand my answer. In your two database sessions, `timezone` is set to a different value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll look into it more